# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and I keep getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse".

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');

ourRequest.onload = function(){
    var ourData  = JSON.parse(ourRequest.resoponseText);
    console.log(ourData[0]);
};
ourRequest.send();
```

Comment: it looks like you have a typo, i imagine it should be `responseText`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've simply misspelt `resoponseText` - It should be `responseText`. You get the error because JavaScript ends up calling `JSON.parse("undefined")`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: you wrote `ourRequest.resoponseText` rather than `ourRequest.responseText`.